# Return only the values if not inside the array in for loop

Tags: javascript

This array contains 1,5,

```
let numberArray = [1,5];
```

I'm trying to print numbers from 1 to 280 except for the values inside the `numberArray`,

```
 for (let i = 1; i < 281; i++) {
    numberArray.forEach((number) => {
      if (number != i) {
        console.log(i);
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm expecting the result to be `2,3,4,6,7...280` without printing 1 and 5 in this case. But I get like this,

[image]

It prints `2 times` each number except `1` and `5`. I want to completely omit the values inside the `numberArray` and print the other values. Really appreciate it if somebody could point me to the bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a bug, your code is doing exactly what you are telling it too.
You have your for loop which happens 280 times and then you have a forEach loop inside that which is happening twice every time the loop goes around. So the Foreach loop is actually happening. 558 times.

You can just use the `.includes` method to check i doesn't exist within the numberArray.

```js
 for (let i = 1; i < 281; i++) {
    if(!numberArray.includes(i)){
       console.log(i);
    }
  }
```